# How To Get Direct Link From Mediafire

Tags: android

I have a download link from mediafire.

```
http://www.mediafire.com/?5tn6rebctezdqlt
```

And I tried use this.

```
http://download949.mediafire.com/bh0f7pom39ig/5tn6rebctezdqlt/MCPEIndir+1.1.apk
```

But nothing changed. How can I use direct link in my app? This is my alert dialog button. And I wanna use update link.

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            MainActivity.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Yeni Sürüm Bulundu");
        alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
        alertDialog.setMessage("Lütfen yeni sürümü indirin.");
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        alertDialog.setButton("Indir", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                                          Uri.parse(http://download949.mediafire.com/bh0f7pom39ig/5tn6rebctezdqlt/MCPEIndir+1.1.apk));
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        alertDialog.show();     
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrade your mediafire account to get direct download links. https://www.mediafire.com/upgrade

Comment: Is this enough? Just upgrade? After upgrade, should I do another things for get direct link? Last question, is Pro enough?

Comment: I am sure of that coz currently I am using mediafire upgraded account. Downloading after calling url by webview or asynctask.

Comment: Check on Pro Feature - "Direct links to files" . Enough with pro .

Comment: Im in mobile. I was trying to see festures of pro plan. Thanks ^^

Comment: Don't forget to mark if you've solved your problem . ;)

Comment: Yes! Thanks :D Can you reach directly to file? http://download949.mediafire.com/bh0f7pom39ig/5tn6rebctezdqlt/MCPEIndir+1.1.apk

Comment: my first +1 to you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can go on the file you need the direct link created then *right click*  choose *share* then on the bottom left, click *more sharing options* you will see the direct link option. I thought this might help someone if your account is not yet upgraded.